# Search using multiple parameters, LIKE, ORDER BY

Tags: php, pdo, sql-order-by, sql-like

I want to create a search form for my site and be able to search by selecting multiple parameters, using LIKE and eventually ORDER BY. Search by name, country and date.

InnoDB, collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci, php 5.6

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['search'])){

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM radio_posts';
    $where = array();
    $params = array();      

    if (!empty($_POST['postRadioName'])) {
        $where[] = "postName LIKE :searchRadioName";
        $params[':searchRadioName'] = '%'.$_POST['postRadioName'].'%';

    }

    if (!empty($_POST['postCountryID'])) {
        $where[] = "postCountryID = :postCountryID";
        $params[':postCountryID'] = $_POST['postCountryID'];
    }


    if (!empty($where)) {
        $sql .= ' WHERE (' . implode(') AND (', $where) . ') ' ;
    }

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

    foreach($params as $param => $value) {
        $stmt->bindParam($param, $value);
    }
    $stmt->execute();    

}

?>
```

My table is radio_posts, there are also a few columns, postID, postName, postCountryID, postDate. In postName I have few rows: *new radio*, *new radio 2*, *new radio 3*. When I search for a term, for example "new", all three rows are displayed, good. If I search by postCountryID, for example "3" only one row is displayed, also good because only one is assigned to id 3. But when I search both, postName "new" and postCountryID "3" no results are displayed. How to solve this? to display the row/s coresponding to both, postName and postCountryID. In phpMyAdmin is working but using the search form it doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM `radio_posts` WHERE postName LIKE '%new%' AND postCountryID = 3
```

Also, if possible, I would like to ask, what is the best approach to order the results by postDate column, ascending, descending.

Comment: Have you tried encapsulating `postName LIKE :searchRadioName` with quotes? I do tend to not use named placeholders, only `?` placeholders with queries so I'm not sure if changing it to `postName LIKE ':searchRadioName'` might produce your expected output.

Comment: Yes the SQL looks correct. Perhaps the "3" is not binding as an int? Especially since HTML form data in PHP is always a string, until you explicitly cast it as something else.

Comment: @Dominic It is always best practice to cast as the correct datatype either way, `$params[':postCountryID'] = $_POST['postCountryID']` should be `$params[':postCountryID'] = (int) $_POST['postCountryID']` - well pointed out but I don't think that is causing the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @Jaquarh. Also, I tend to use `$stmt->bindParam($param, $value, \PDO::PARAM_INT);` (or the appropriate datatype PDO constant).

Comment: Try changing `'%'.$_POST['postRadioName'].'%'` to `"'%{$_POST['postRadioName']}%'"` - This will then include the quotes when you bind the value to the placeholder.

Comment: I have tried $where[] = "postName LIKE ?"; $params[] = '%'.$_POST['postRadioName'].'%';   
 then $params[':postCountryID'] = (int) $_POST['postCountryID']   , changed
 '%'.$_POST['postRadioName'].'%' to "'%{$_POST['postRadioName']}%'" , nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

After replacing `$stmt->bindParam($param, $value);` with `$stmt->bindValue($param, $value);` the code is working as expected. One result is retrieved for the term "new" and country ID = 3.